# How to change the function from onEdit to onChange in AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheets file that receives data from Google Form, I would like for every new data entered to open a new sheet with a fixed template, this operation to be carried out after checking that there is no existing sheet with that name, using the onEdit function I manage to do it but not using onChange, I would appreciate help.
I'll just point out, the reason I need to use the onChange function is because I'm not editing the file, but it receives data from Google Form

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "Form" || e.range.columnStart != 8) return;
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const template = sh.getSheetByName("TEMPLATE");
  let data = e.range.offset(0, -7, 1, 8).getValues();
  let Tik = data\[0\]\[1\];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var itt = ss.getSheetByName("Num" + Tik);

  if (!(itt == null)) return;
  let newSheet = template.copyTo(sh).setName("Num " + Tik);
  newSheet.getRange("A2").setValue(Tik);
}
```

Comment: The only trigger that will work for you is the onFormSubmit for Spreadsheets.  Their  are no triggers that fire for non user edits.

Comment: All of the submitted data is in the values key of the event object as an array with timestamp being  element zero followed by all of the question answers

Comment: - [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)